# Why does the request-uri contains context-path for default application?

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, glassfish-3, contextroot

Setting application `App` as the default application will leads to an empty context-path value when calling `HttpServletRequest.getContextPath()` from an url without the context-path.

Requesting site using following url in browser-bar (no `/App`!): `/foo/bar.xhtml`

will lead to following values:

`HttpServletRequest.getContextPath()` = ""
`HttpServletRequest.getServletPath()` = "/foo/bar.xhtml"
`HttpServletRequest.getRequestURI()` = "/App/foo/bar.xhtml"

Should `/App` not be removed when retrieving the request-uri?

---

The following line of code (which is used in many so-questions) to remove the context-path from the uri won't work anymore:

```
request.getRequestURI().substring(request.getContextPath().length());
```

or should this safely be replaced with:?

```
request.getContextPath() + request.getServletPath()
```

---

*Using mojarra 2.1.23 on Glassfish 3.1.2*

**Glassfish settings:**
Application `App` - Context Root: `/App`
Virtual Server - default web module: `App`

So that I can omit `/App` from the URL.

Comment: This is not JSF specific. This is servletcontainer specific (look, `HttpServletRequest` is from `javax.servlet` package not `javax.faces`). Which one are you using? What exactly is it, the "default application" setting? Do you really have `/App` in URL and yet the context path returns empty? I'd expect that you could just omit `/App` altogether from URL.

Comment: Glassfish 3.1.2 and no `/App` is not in the URL in the browser.  Updated the question.

Comment: Look like a GF bug. You should at least set "context root" setting in GlassFish to `/`. This can be done in admin console, or in EAR's `application.xml` (if you have any one), or in WAR's `glassfish-web.xml`. Let me know if that works, then I'll turn it into an answer.

Comment: I am sorry i cannot test this. Changing root to `/` via console is not working since i run into this exception/bug: `No context matching / deployed on virtual server server` And i am wasting too much time on trying a workaround for another gf bug, i also tried the proposed solution on so but it did not worked. I will try to replace the code with the second line in my question later.